# Google tasks API patch overrides time portion

Tags: google-tasks

I'm trying to use patch as an update option for a google tasks from the API https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks/patch. So far as I understand it should update only sent fields, but even if I'm sending only title, it overrides time portion, meaning: I add google task from google tasks app, set date and time; then in my app with https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks/patch I'm sending title update, task becomes all day and losing time portion

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide a small code snippet showing the PATCH request with an example of the patch contents?

Answer (score 0):

### This is an issue that has been reported

The issue is tracked on Google's public issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128979662

The [Support documentation](https://developers.google.com/tasks/support#bugs) says you can report this on Google Issue Tracker. In this case I would find the report created for this and upvote it.

As you mentioned [Google Tasks documentation](https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks#Task) says that the field **due** should not be affected if your are not explicitly changing that field:

> Due date of the task (as a RFC 3339 timestamp). Optional. The due date only records date information; the time portion of the timestamp is discarded when setting the due date. It isn't possible to read or write the time that a task is due via the API.